# i Using 2 JQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website works well, using JQuery. On one page, I call the JQuery when the document (page) is ready, using

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
            autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
        })     
        });
</script>
```

Another page, which uses a different JQuery plugin, does

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Now, I need to have both of these plugins on the same page.

The following code stops the JQuery working completely, and I'm lost to what is the correct syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
            autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
        })
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });

</script>
```

I also tried

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
               mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
               manualContinuousScrolling: true,
               autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
           });
           $(".fancybox").fancybox();
       });
</script>
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: the code isn't where the problem lies. It's more likely that you've included two copies of jquery incorrectly.

Comment: @KevinB, no, I realised this could be an issue - both use the same JQuery and as such, I only reference it once

Comment: Your first attempt should have worked (assuming you included jquery and the plugins properly,) the second has a syntax error.

Comment: Under "I also tried," could you please indent that code? I think it might help a little...

Comment: Do you have any errors in your dev tools JS console?

Comment: hmmm - I admit, I typed the second by hand, not copied form VS, but, it's still good to know that the syntax was correct, thank you.

Comment: At the end of the first function you have a ',' instead of ';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"i also tried"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize the plugin with no custom options
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
    })             }),
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

i think it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize the plugin with no custom options
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
    });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

Comment: If this syntax is correct, then issue must be else where (and outside the code I've provided). But, knowing this is correct will help me debug, so thanks...